# R didn't save the row name when import of CSV file

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to generate a heat map using sample data as attached image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjVs5.png).

However, when I import the csv file (sample as attached) it doesn't save the row name, but instead give me some numbers.

When I convert to data matrix it doesn't save the row name:

```
   Taxon Planococcus_sp_CAU13 Planococcus_versutus_L10_15T
```

[1,]    15                  1.0                         69.6
 [2,]    18                 69.6                          1.0

May I know how to import the data properly?

I am using:

x = read.csv("mydata.csv", header = TRUE)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's an actual Comma delimited format? May be a tab delimited (or even space-delimited) file. Try either `x<-read.delim("mydata.csv", header=TRUE)` or `x<-read.csv("mydata.csv", header=TRUE, sep=" ")`.

Comment: try using rownames("matrix object name") <-x$taxon

Comment: Thanks guy! It's working fine now.